# Android Two-way databinding for Nullable Float on EditText

Tags: android, kotlin, 2-way-object-databinding

I'm trying to use two-way data-binding on an EditText. However, my variable type is a nullable Float (I'm using Kotlin by the way). 
I keep getting databinding error, cannot find the getter for android:text with value type of Float.

```
android:text='@={travelRecord.weeksOfStay+""}'
```

Would not work because it will come up as null, but I want it as blank when the variable is null.

```
android:text='@={travelRecord.weeksOfStay? "":travelRecord.weeksOfStay+""}'
```

Would not work because it won't recognize two way data binding.

I read somewhere about BindingAdapter and InverseBindingAdapter, but cannot get it to work. How do I specify them to recognize my EditText?

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/length_of_stay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:text='@={travelRecord.weeksOfStay}' />
```

Comment: have you tried `@{safeUnbox(travelRecord.weeksOfStay)}`?

Comment: What's safeUnbox? I got cannot find method safeUnbox(java.lang.Float) in class android.databinding.ViewDataBinding

Comment: This is binding framework's method. Just try it out.

Comment: yeah... not working,,, I got cannot find method safeUnbox(java.lang.Float)

Comment: you got this working?

Comment: no..............

Comment: Are you trying `@={safeUnbox(travelRecord.weeksOfStay)}` or `@{safeUnbox(travelRecord.weeksOfStay)}`? Notice the correct one is the one without the equals (`=`) sign